# .exe not showing "Press any key to continue..."

Tags: c++

[image]
In Visual Studio whenever I start without debugging, the .exe file that shows up does not contain the phrase "Press any key to continue..." like it usually does. The screen just has the flashing cursor at the beginning. Is there any easy fix to this? I have commented out some of my code and the phrase shows back up.

This is the code that I have commented out: I have all of the variables and classes declared correctly.

```
void Maze::addPaths()
{
    Coordinate currentLocation;
    Coordinate startLocation;
    Coordinate endLocation; //not used yet
    std::stack<Coordinate> stack;

    currentLocation.row = (((rand() % HEIGHT) / 2) * 2);
    currentLocation.column = (((rand() % WIDTH) / 2) * 2);

    startLocation = currentLocation;
    grid[currentLocation.row][currentLocation.column] = START;
    player = currentLocation;
    do 
    {
        //drawMaze();
        bool canMoveUp = !(currentLocation.row == 0 || grid[currentLocation.row - 2][currentLocation.column] != WALL);
        bool canMoveDown = !(currentLocation.row == HEIGHT - 1 || grid[currentLocation.row + 2][currentLocation.column] != WALL);
        bool canMoveLeft = !(currentLocation.column == 0 || grid[currentLocation.row][currentLocation.column - 2] != WALL);
        bool canMoveRight = !(currentLocation.column == WIDTH - 1 || grid[currentLocation.row][currentLocation.column + 2] != WALL);

        if (canMoveUp || canMoveDown || canMoveLeft || canMoveRight)
        {
            stack.push(currentLocation);

            //choose random location to dig
            bool moveFound = false;
            while (!moveFound)
            {
                int direction = rand() % 4;
                if (direction == 0 && canMoveUp)
                {
                    moveFound = true;
                    grid[currentLocation.row - 2][currentLocation.column] = PATH;
                    grid[currentLocation.row - 1][currentLocation.column] = PATH;
                    currentLocation.row -= 2;
                }
                else if (direction == 1 && canMoveDown)
                {
                    moveFound = true;
                    grid[currentLocation.row + 2][currentLocation.column] = PATH;
                    grid[currentLocation.row + 1][currentLocation.column] = PATH;
                    currentLocation.row += 2;
                }
                else if (direction == 2 && canMoveLeft)
                {
                    moveFound = true;
                    grid[currentLocation.row][currentLocation.column - 2] = PATH;
                    grid[currentLocation.row][currentLocation.column - 1] = PATH;
                    currentLocation.column -= 2;
                }
                else if (direction == 3 && canMoveRight)
                {
                    moveFound = true;
                    grid[currentLocation.row][currentLocation.column + 2] = PATH;
                    grid[currentLocation.row][currentLocation.column - 2] = PATH;
                    currentLocation.column += 2;
                cout << "yay";
                }
            }
        }
        else if (!stack.empty())
        {
            currentLocation = stack.top();
            stack.pop();
        }
    } while (!stack.empty());
    //addDestinationToGrid();
    cout << "no";
}
```

Comment: The debugger shows that prompt. So it ain't there without the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your main `do-while` loops in endless cycle. How do you initialize grid?

Comment: I initialize grid with this: char grid[WIDTH][HEIGHT]; (Where WIDTH and HEIGHT are constant integers.  @bolov

Comment: I mean what value stored in grid. And in Your code direction always equal 0. It's means it `canMoveUp ` get false, and at least one `canMove...` variable get true in internal `while (!moveFound)` cycle no one condition is not performed. Hence `currentLocation` don't do step and on next iteration `do-while` cycle will be checked same point.

Comment: And in condition `currentLocation.row == 0 || grid[currentLocation.row - 2][currentLocation.column] != WALL` if row equal 1 then `grid[-1][col]` can still exceed `grid` memory border. Similarly for the other

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, `system("PAUSE");` will prompt a user with the text:

```
Press any key to continue...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being that I was traveling out of the bounds of the array named grid and I has also mixed up my row and columns in my for loops.